Django why is my image refusing to upload
For my website- I implemented a profile pic you can add to your profile which works:
models.py
class Profileuser(models.Model):
owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
tagline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
website = models.URLField(blank=True)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="profiles/", blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.id} | {self.name}"

views.py
class ProfileuserCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Profileuser
    fields = ['name', 'profile_pic', 'tagline', 'bio', 'website']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('recipes-home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(ProfileuserCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

Urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

However- when I tried to implement adding photos to my recipe posts- the images just don't upload, I can see the folder sitting empty
models.py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipe_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="imagerecipes/", blank=True)
    ingredients = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipes-detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

views.py
class RecipeCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = models.Recipe
    fields = ['title', 'recipe_image', 'ingredients', 'description']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

I don't understand why one works but the other doesn't as the code is virtually the same- if I upload via admin- it does work, I have also tested profile pictures and it still allows me to upload them.
No error messages- the photo just doesn't upload into the folder...
Edit: Requested to add template-
This isn't the issue as the form displays correctly and allows me to attach an image, same as with the profile picture, it just doesn't actually upload into the folder.
{% extends 'recipes/base.html' %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <h1 class="text=2x1 my-4">Add Recipe!</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <input class="px-8 py-2 text-white bg-orange-600 rounded-lg hover:bg-orange-700 hover:cursor-pointed" type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <a href="{% url 'recipes-home' %}">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

Edit- Updated template to include: enctype="multipart/form-data"
Still getting the same error- the form submits successfully but the image doesn't upload into the folder
{% extends 'recipes/base.html' %}
{% load tailwind_filters %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <h1 class="text=2x1 my-4">Add Recipe!</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <input class="px-8 py-2 text-white bg-orange-600 rounded-lg hover:bg-orange-700 hover:cursor-pointed" type="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="Save">
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <a href="{% url 'recipes-home' %}">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}


Please [edit] and show us your template, I am guessing the problem is there.

I added the template but I am pretty sure this isn't the issue- the form displays correctly and allows me to search my files and add a file- it just doesn't upload to the folder when I press submit- the recipe is saved and all the other details are there.

As shown in the duplicate your form tag needs enctype="multipart/form-data" if you want to upload files.

@AbdulAzizBarkat This didn't fix the issue it is still the same

Please [edit] and show us your updated code.

That attribute is supposed to be added on the form tag not the input tag.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Legend that has fixed it- I understand now why one worked and the other didn't in my form tag for the profile user I did have enctype already which is why it worked! Thanks so much!
